# How to use Sensors in Codename one

Tags: codenameone

I would like to have a hidden container on the West Side of a BorderLayout in a Form.  Then, I would like for a user to be abel to slide their finger on the west side of the screen to make the container appear.  and then swipe the other way to make it disappear.  Is that possible? Would love help.  Thanks!

Andrew

P.S. If this is not possible, would it be possible to overlap a container on the West side of the borderLayout over the center container?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with sensors.

There is builtin functionality for side menu bar which allows just that just use the [Toolbar](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Toolbar.html) and add a command to the side menu:

```
Form hi = new Form("Toolbar", new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
hi.getToolbar().addCommandToSideMenu("Sidemenu", null, e -> Log.p("Clicked"));
hi.show();
```

If this isn't what you actually want and you "really" was a side menu you can just use a pointer dragged listener on the parent form. Just set the preferred size of your container to `0 ,0` and when the drag events drag to the right set the preferred size accordingly and `revalidate()`.